# XCode - Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Lately I've started to take up a course for learning swift to devolp iOS OS X and Watch OS apps. I'm taking this course on udacity. The first step is to download a project and put it in a folder on your desktop. I had to open the app and then run it, which should've worked. But not for me somehow. I hit run and the following error showed up (this is the complete error log):
[image]

[image]

Some poeple suggested that I should update my XCode but I already have. I currently have XCode 7.3! I'm quite new to this platform, that's also why I'm doing this course, so I don't really know what I have to do. Can someone please tell me what's going on here?

Comment: Is this your only error? There should be a number near the red icon and it should be more than one. If it is more then one, inspect the other errors. This just looks like an effect of a previous error.

Comment: There is indeed a number, but it says 1. So this is the only error I'm getting. I'd know if I had more than 1

Comment: There's also a class which is what I think corrupt. because it only has these characters in it: "Ôæ≠ﬁÔæ≠ﬁqcaJÔæ≠ﬁhJ0ççˇˇˇ2ççˇˇˇ$5y$Äˇˇˇ% 7.ÄˇˇˇÔæ≠ﬁÔæ≠ﬁP‚—Äˇˇˇﬂ‚Äˇˇˇ Ë—Äˇˇˇ∞B‚ÄˇˇˇÄ+€"

Comment: You can open the "Console" app and check that if you reproduce it, there may be something along the lines of "swiftc segmentation fault" or something like this. If this is a case you have found a compiler bug - try to update Xcode, report a radar.apple.com. If not, there's something else wrong

Comment: Delete derived data from Windows->Projects->select your project and delete derived data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result of a corrupted swift class. If you encounter a class looking similar to the following code:

```
Ôæ≠ﬁÔæ≠ﬁqcaJÔæ≠ﬁhJ0ççˇˇˇ2ççˇˇˇ$5y$Äˇˇˇ% 7.ÄˇˇˇÔæ≠ﬁÔæ≠ﬁP‚—Äˇˇˇﬂ‚Äˇˇˇ Ë—Äˇˇˇ∞B‚ÄˇˇˇÄ+€
```

Try to re-create the class or re-download it. This solved my problem and to me, it would look like the only solution possible for a corrupted class.

Answer (score 1):

Delete derived data.

> **Windows->Projects->select your project and delete derived data**

This worked for me for couple of projects which i downloaded from internet.

Answer (score 0):

I do everything restarts Xcode, rebuild Project, adding toolChains lock unlock them,
so there are two possibilities
first, maybe you install the beta version of Xcode

or try this, this work for me->
I tried to run a project in Xcode12/Swift4, while the project was written on Xcode8/Swift3
so I install  Xcode version 11.7 and run this work for me.
if you not done with 11.7 then install another version of Xcode and try the appreciated version
May this help you